# Django CBV: reuse form with fields subset

Tags: django

I have a `FormView` with a `ModelForm` to create a particular model.

Now let's say I want to be able to edit that model, but only a subset of fields, so only these can be modified and validation will be run only on these, and not the others (and the others won't appear as "required", etc).

Is it possible to reuse the existing `ModelForm` in this scenario, or do I have to create a new form altogether?

Comment: One solution would be to subclass your `ModelForm` and redefine its `Meta`. Or define the form's required fields in the form's `__init__` and you will instantiate it with the fields you need

Comment: Your quesion is unclear to me, are you sure that by "model" you don't mean "instance"?

Comment: @vmonteco of course I mean an instance, and a db entry once the form save is performed.

Comment: @MihaiZamfir so I should just define the fields I am leaving out as required False in the new `ModelForm` inheriting from the one I already have?

Comment: @dabadaba subclass your modelform and in `class Meta:` just say `fields = (your_new_list_of_fields, )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass some sort of "flag" to let the form know which fields to treat differently.

A code example will make more sense:

```
# your view
class SpecialFormView(FormView):
   # [...your view attributes..]

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super(SpecialFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs['is_special'] = True
       return kwargs

# your form
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
   # [... your fields and meta..]

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       is_special = kwargs.pop('is_special', False)
       super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       if is_special:
           for field in ['field_1', 'field_2']:
               self.fields[field].required = False
```

Comment: oh I like this approach. Thank you.